Select ID if there was change in History table
I have a history table that contains a form ID along with the change date and status of a form.
I am looking to select only the forms that have at some point been in Completed status, and have then moved to ANY other status and pull back the formID plus the date of the following change for that form. I've tried using min( ) to select the completion date and comparing but I am still not getting my results back.



FormId
Status
Date




100000
New
10-1-2024 15:00


100000
In Progress
10-1-2024 18:00


100000
Completed
10-1-2024 22:00


100001
New
10-1-2024 22:00


100000
In Progress
10-2-2024 04:00


100000
Revaluate
10-3-2024 06:00


100002
New
10-3-2024 08:00


100002
In Progress
10-3-2024 10:00


100002
Completed
10-3-2024 12:00


100003
New
10-4-2024 12:00


100003
In Progress
10-5-2024 10:00


100003
Completed
10-5-2024 12:00


100003
Revaluate
10-6-2024 09:00



I am expecting:



FormId
CompleteDate
Status
FirstUpdateDate




100000
10-1-2024 22:00
In Progress
10-2-2024 04:00


100003
10-5-2024 12:00
Revaluate
10-6-2024 09:00



Any guidance is greatly appreciated.
I have tried using min and partition and it didn't work for me. With the below, I am getting the correct formIds and first CompleteDate, but am getting the last update date, not the one immediately after the complete day. I have tried +1, didn't work.
In my real scenario, I have a more complex table structure so apologies if what I tried doesn't make sense, I tried to clean it up:
select distinct 
    base.formId, t.originalCompleteDay, m.Status, m.FirstUpdateDate 
from 
    BaseTable base 
inner join 
    (select 
         p.formId, p.originalCompleteDay
     from 
         (select 
              h.*, 
              min(case when status = "Completed" then ChangeDate end) over (partition by h.formId) as originalCompleteDay 
          from 
              History h) p 
     where 
         Status != "Completed" 
         and ChangeDate > originalCompleteDay) t on t.formId = base.formId  
inner join 
    (select  
         l.formId, l.FirstUpdateDate, Status
     from 
         (select 
              h.*, max(ChangeDate) over (partition by h.formId) as FirstUpdateDate 
          from 
              History h) l) m on m.formId = base.formId 


Is it possible for a form to go to completed status more than once?

You can use the LAG() window function to access the prior status and date for each row. Once you have that, you can filter for Status <> 'Completed' and PriorStatus = 'Completed'.
WITH HistoryWithPriorStatus AS (
    SELECT
        *,
        LAG(Status) OVER(PARTITION BY FormId ORDER BY Date) AS PriorStatus,
        LAG(Date) OVER(PARTITION BY FormId ORDER BY Date) AS PriorDate
    FROM History
)
SELECT FormId, PriorDate AS CompleteDate, Status, Date AS FirstUpdateDate
FROM HistoryWithPriorStatus
WHERE Status <> 'Completed'
AND PriorStatus = 'Completed'

Results:



FormId
CompleteDate
Status
FirstUpdateDate




100000
2024-10-01 22:00
In Progress
2024-10-02 04:00


100003
2024-10-05 12:00
Revaluate
2024-10-06 09:00



See this db<>fiddle for a demo.
The above approach requires only one table reference, but will perform a full table scan.
Other approaches may have better performance with large data sets using multiple index seeks, but only if the appropriate supporting indexes are defined. For example, the following will use index seeks to retrieve rows with Status = 'Completed' and another index seek (in a CROSS APPLY) to retrieve the following history row for each. Then latter is then filtered for Status <> 'Completed'.
CREATE INDEX IX_History_Status
    ON History(Status)
    INCLUDE(FormId, Date)
CREATE INDEX IX_History_FormId_Date
    ON History(FormId, Date)
    INCLUDE(Status)

SELECT
    H1.FormId,
    H1.Date AS CompleteDate,
    HNEXT.Status, 
    HNEXT.Date AS FirstUpdateDate
FROM History H1
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 H2.*
    FROM History H2
    WHERE H2.FormId = H1.FormId
    AND H2.Date > H1.Date
    ORDER BY H2.Date
) HNEXT
WHERE H1.Status = 'Completed'
AND HNEXT.Status <> 'Completed'

See this db<>fiddle for a demo of both approaches and their execution plans.

This! There are several functional solutions here, but the LAG() window function will tend to have -- by far -- the best performance, and do it with the least code, and bonus points for also showing the exception case.

Also: I did not know db fiddle could show execution plans like that, which is so cool.

I dont know where your base table comes from, nor its content, but this gets what you are looking for.
select
        pq.formid,
        pq.CompleteDate,
        h3.status,
        pq.FirstUpdateDate
    from
    (
select
        h.formID,
        min( h.date ) CompleteDate,
        min( h2.date ) FirstUpdateDate
    from
        History h
            join History h2
                on h.formid = h2.formid
                and h.date < h2.date
    where
        h.status = 'Completed'
    group by
        h.formid ) pq
        join History h3
            on pq.formid = h3.formid
            AND pq.FirstUpdateDate = h3.date

The first "FROM" clause is a PreQuery (alias pq) that specifically looks only for those records with a "Completed" status -- AND joins to the history table after it on the same ID PLUS the first record AFTER the completed.  In this case, ID 100002 wont be included because it did not have any subsequent status.
By getting the MIN() second history table "date" greater than completed, we are getting the 3 primary parts... The ID, the FIRST Completed date AND the first subsequent date AFTER the first completed.
With this result, I joined again to the history table for the qualified ID AND matching date/time to get the status of that entry.
Now, if it is possible for a single form ID to have multiple statuses with the same exact date/time, you may need to shift to a partition/over to get the first entry.  However, without such other qualifying condition, you could have a race condition on which "first time" after completed wins, or with this, you would see MULTIPLE entries.  However, it DOES get what you are looking for.

I think you're on the right track, but the issue arises from the fact that the max() function in the second subquery (FirstUpdateDate) is pulling the last update rather than the one immediately following the Completed status. Instead, let's use ROW_NUMBER() to pinpoint the exact first update that follows Completed.
Here is my approch:

The date a form first reached the Completed status (CompleteDate).
The status and date of the first change after the form was completed (FirstUpdateDate).

Here is the Solution
We can use window functions to partition the data by FormId, making it easier to isolate both the first Completed date and the first change date after completion.

Okay now, Identify the First Completed Date for Each Form:

Use a window function to mark the earliest Completed status date for each FormId.


Then Select the First Status Change After Completion:

Filter out rows where the status is Completed and look for the next available date for each form after the CompleteDate.



Here is the SQL query:
WITH CompletedForms AS (
    -- Step 1: Get the first **Completed** date for each FormId
    SELECT 
        FormId,
        MIN(CASE WHEN Status = 'Completed' THEN Date END) AS CompleteDate
    FROM history
    GROUP BY FormId
),
FirstUpdateAfterComplete AS (
    -- Step 2: For each form, find the first status change date after **Completed**
    SELECT 
        h.FormId,
        c.CompleteDate,
        h.Status,
        h.Date AS FirstUpdateDate,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY h.FormId ORDER BY h.Date) AS RowAfterComplete
    FROM history h
    INNER JOIN CompletedForms c ON h.FormId = c.FormId
    WHERE h.Date > c.CompleteDate
)

-- Step 3: Filter out to only keep the first update after completion
SELECT 
    f.FormId,
    f.CompleteDate,
    f.Status,
    f.FirstUpdateDate
FROM FirstUpdateAfterComplete f
WHERE f.RowAfterComplete = 1
ORDER BY f.FormId;

Here is your Expected Output
With this query, you should get results similar to:



FormId
CompleteDate
Status
FirstUpdateDate




100000
2024-10-01 22:00:00
In Progress
2024-10-02 04:00:00


100003
2024-10-05 12:00:00
Revaluate
2024-10-06 09:00:00



It should work even if the history table is large, as long as you have indexes on FormId and Date.
Here is the actual result in DataGrip


We can use CROSS APPLY with TOP 1.
The idea is to find the first row (that's why to use TOP 1 and the ORDER BY clause) with the same FormId, but another status in our table (that's what the conditions in the WHERE clause do).
Only FormIds will be considered that have a row with Status = Completed.
SELECT
  h1.FormId,
  h1.[date] AS CompleteDate,
  h2.Status,
  h2.[date] AS FirstUpdateDate
FROM history h1
CROSS APPLY (
  SELECT TOP 1 
    h2.Status,
    h2.[date]
  FROM history h2
  WHERE 
    h1.FormId = h2.FormId 
    AND h1.Status = 'Completed' 
    AND h2.Status <> 'Completed'
    AND h1.[date] < h2.[date]
  ORDER BY h2.[date]
) h2
ORDER BY h1.FormId, h1.[Date];

This produces the expected result for the given sample data:



FormId
CompleteDate
Status
FirstUpdateDate




100000
2024-10-01 22:00:00
In Progress
2024-10-02 04:00:00


100003
2024-10-05 12:00:00
Revaluate
2024-10-06 09:00:00



Note: Above query would return all rows per FormId with Status = Completed together with their first other Status afterwards.
I don't know whether this is intended and if we can ever have multiple rows with Status = Completed for the same FormId. So lets add following two further rows to our table:
INSERT INTO history 
VALUES
('100000','Completed','2024-10-01 16:00'),
('100003','Completed','2024-10-05 06:00');

Now above query will produce this result:



FormId
CompleteDate
Status
FirstUpdateDate




100000
2024-10-01 16:00:00
In Progress
2024-10-01 18:00:00


100000
2024-10-01 22:00:00
In Progress
2024-10-02 04:00:00


100003
2024-10-05 06:00:00
In Progress
2024-10-05 10:00:00


100003
2024-10-05 12:00:00
Revaluate
2024-10-06 09:00:00



If this is possible and we don't want to get all those rows, but for example to return the earliest "completed row" with the next other status only, then we will use our query in a CTE and append the row number sorted by date (or by something else if we want).
Then we select those rows with row number 1 only in our final result:
WITH sub AS
(SELECT
  h1.FormId,
  h1.[date] AS CompleteDate,
  h2.Status,
  h2.[date] AS FirstUpdateDate,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY FormId ORDER BY h1.[date]) AS rn
FROM history h1
CROSS APPLY (
  SELECT TOP 1 
    h2.Status,
    h2.[date]
  FROM history h2
  WHERE 
    h1.FormId = h2.FormId 
    AND h1.Status = 'Completed' 
    AND h2.Status <> 'Completed'
    AND h1.[date] < h2.[date]
  ORDER BY h2.[date]
) h2)
SELECT 
  FormId,
  CompleteDate,
  Status,
  FirstUpdateDate
FROM sub
WHERE 
  rn = 1
ORDER BY sub.FormId, sub.CompleteDate;

And this query returns again two rows only:



FormId
CompleteDate
Status
FirstUpdateDate




100000
2024-10-01 16:00:00
In Progress
2024-10-01 18:00:00


100003
2024-10-05 06:00:00
In Progress
2024-10-05 10:00:00



We can verify all these use cases and their results on this db<>fiddle
